# Is entailment biconditional or conditional?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

When we say a KB entails Q it means that it is never the case that KB is true and Q is false. Does this mean entailment is similar to the conditional statement KB -> Q? I'm confused because our textbook keeps using "if and only if".

Comment: Entails means implies, it is not a biconditional. If your textbook mixes these up, burn it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entailment is closest to the material conditional: To say "$KB$ implies $Q,$" or "If $KB$, then $Q$," is to assert $$KB \rightarrow Q$$

To say "$KB \;\text{ if and only if }  \;Q$" is to say: $$KB \rightarrow Q\quad\text{ AND }\quad Q \rightarrow KB$$

In this case, in order for the *biconditional* to be true, $KB$ and $Q$ must both be true, or must both be false. If their truth-values differ, then exactly one or the other of the two conditionals must be false, and hence, the biconditional is false.

Comment: I've upvoted this, because the distinction between the conditional and the biconditional made here does come as useful and matters more than anything else for this question.  But, at least the people who write Wikipedia use "entailment" and "conditional" with different meanings.

Comment: @amWhy: Get another TU! +1

Answer (score 1):

Entailment doesn't actually refer to the conditional nor does it refer to the biconditional.  Entailment often refers to [semantic consequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence).  In symbols, we can write KB entailing Q as

A1: KB |= Q.

The conditional (KB→Q) qualifying as true doesn't refer to semantic consequence in the same way.  If we put (KB→Q) qualifying as true in the same symbolism, we can write

A2: |= (KB→Q).

A2 has a truth-functional connective.  A1 doesn't have such a connective.  In many logical systems A1 and A2 are closely related, because of the rule of detachment (or "modus ponens"), and a meta-theorem which says that if A1 holds, then A2 holds also (a semantic version of a deduction theorem).  So, entailment does often come as related, in some sense, to the conditional.  It is *not* similarly related to the biconditional.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, thank you.